# Jmeter no GUI mode runs .jmx does not include run the overwrite method getDefaultParameters()

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-5.0

I create a java sampler .jmx in jmeter GUI mode with an element CSV Data Set Config. It contains a getDefaultParameters() method which is a overwrite method to initialize parameters. It runs well in GUI mode. However it does not initialize parameters when running in no GUI mode. Because it does not print the log I have added in the getDefaultParameters() method. The command I have used is "jmeter -n -t OpenAPIAutomationTestPlatform0928.jmx".
Some logs from jmeter:
[image]

[image]

[image]

So it gives out the error NonPointerException when try to get the parameter come from CSV Data Set Config.

How can I initialize parameters using no GUI mode? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In JMeter 5 new [changes](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html) you can add parameters' initialization inside groovy script added to file `jsr223.init.file` in your bin folder

> Bug 62700 - Introduce jsr223.init.file to allow calling a JSR-223 script on JMeter startup